# Host LAN interface from iPhone/ Mac App

Tags: iphone, macos, interface

Okay, so what I want to do is be able to control certain aspects of my application from anywhere on a LAN, through a website. Mainly to download log files.

Could anybody point me in the direction I need to be going please.

Basically, the application would be downloaded, then installed. When launched the application would be running, which would also 'host' a web interface, so log files can be downloaded easily on other devices, and simple commands can be sent with html forms.

What I am having a hard time doing is making the os x /ios application host my html files, so that they can be accessed at 192.168.x.x/*.html. And viewed by other users of the LAN.

The interface is very simple and would be mainly sending html forms and downloading log files.

Comment: instead of trying to implement a web server in the iPhone why don't you send the files from the device to a fixed real server when you have info to send and collect in the central location? wouldn't this be much much simpler?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to embed HTTP server functionality in your app. There is a multitude of ways to do this, and which one you want to use depends heavily on your needs. For example, I found [this tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html) straight away.